# How to Implement PageTransformer with Swipeable Tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-pagetransformer

In my example code i have three Swipeable Tabs in MainActivity.java namely : Android, IOS and WINDOWS and i am using swipe to switch between Tabs.

Now, i have to implement PageTransformer with Swipeable Tabs, so here i need your help, is it possible, if yes so how ?

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    
                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

        ..............
    }
}
```

Here is what i want to implement in my program :

[image]

and this is how my Tab looks :

[image]

Comment: As suggested by @Squonk, did you follow [Customize the Animation with PageTransformer](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer)? Did you face any problem?

Comment: @Moon Can u give example how that lokks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution [here](http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/create-viewpager-transitions-a-pagertransformer-example/), its really easy to implement

Usage is pretty straightforward, just attach a PageTransformer to the ViewPager:

```
viewpager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        // do transformation here
        }
});
```

rotates the pages around their Z axis by 30 degrees; you don’t need to normalize for this one. The effect is similar to the cover flow UI pattern:

```
@Override
public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
    page.setRotationY(position * -30);
}
```

so here is my final code, which i used:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {                       
                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    
                    }
                });

        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);        
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new PageTransformer() {

            public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

                page.setRotationY(position * -30); // animation style... change as you want..
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `setPageTransformer()` to do this type of navigation..
use below code to your pager..

Add This Code To Your `MainActivity.java`

```
Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager); // you have defined view pager as `TAB`

    Tab.setPageTransformer(false, new PageTransformer() {

            public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

                page.setRotationY(position * -30); // animation style... change as you want..
            }
        });
        Tab.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }
```

Get More Animation Styles From Here.. [Customize the Animation with PageTransformer](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer) or  [ViewPager transitions](http://andraskindler.com/blog/2013/create-viewpager-transitions-a-pagertransformer-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Create an inner class of your `Activity`...

```
public class MyPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        // Do your transform here
    }
}
```

Then in your `Activity` you can set it on your `ViewPager`. Example...

```
Tab.setPageTransformer(true, new MyPageTransformer());
```

Read more at [Customize the Animation with PageTransformer](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer) There are even a couple of examples of transforms to try out and to customize yourself.